# Android: How can I share the contents of a Couchbase database between devices? (And/or how to export Couchbase to XML)

Tags: android, xml, database, backup, couchbase-lite

I want to be able to make a backup of the data in my application, and potentially share this backup between Android devices. I am using Couchbase. I have found many resources regarding exporting an SQLite database to XML, but none for Couchbase.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this command to export couch-base to SQLlight.

```
> cbbackup http://<host>:8091 <backup_folder> -u <user> -p <pass> -b <bucket>
```